# Routing to Controller in ActiveAdmin 1.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, rails-routing

`rake routes` gives the output

```
POST    /admin/users(.:format)    admin/users/new
```

But where is the `new` action executed? The `/admin/user` is the registered resource. There are no actions. However creating a new user through the standard AA form puts my user in the database but which controller is used?

**UPDATE:**

I want to create a new user using ActiveAdmin with a password and store the hashed password using devise.  The new action works in my normal user controller which i test through rails console

```
@user=User.create(params.permit(:name, :phone, :active, :password_digest
@user.password = Devise.friendly_token
```

So far i hacked the  action  in the AA user.rb resource like this:(basically the same statements encapsulated in `controller do`...)

```
controller do
  def new 
@user.password = Devise.friendly_token
    @user=User.create(params.permit(:name, :phone, :active, :password_digest
```

The Issue i have now it that the user gets saved in my db but with an unshashed password.(?)
The [live demo](http://demo.activeadmin.info/admin) and the [documentation](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modifying-the-controller) are a bit short on detailed information or examples on this issue.

Comment: Is this a User resource? but why you'd want to create user in `new` action? And the details on "unshashed password"? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: Yes User is a resource. I want to not use the `new` action because its storing the password as plain text  in the db.  I want to change that

Comment: I never tried manually creating user in AA, but if the User model is using Devise you would want to create the user using `params[:password]` and `params[:password_confirmation]` for the password field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActiveAdmin Gem creates a `Admin::UsersController` on the fly, based on the configuration of you `admin/user.rb`

Comment: Ok that sounds good. But where do i find that controller? I tried to `grep` it but i can't find it.

Comment: I still havent found the part where my request is processed. Webrick gave me `Started POST "/admin/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-11 16:34:31 +0200 Processing by Admin::UsersController#create as HTML` But where is this UsersController?

Comment: The Controller don't exist on your filesystem, it's only exist only at runtime in your process. Why do you want to know that file? Do you want to change something on that controller? If yes, post what do you want to change, then I can help you

Comment: Thanks Timo for the offer. I updated my question with more details

Comment: Ok i now got it working i  created a new form with a `:password` and `:password_confirmation` fields and now it works

Answer (score 1):

ActiveAdmin uses [inherited resources gem](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) for the default controller actions. If you want to overwrite the `new` controller action, you can overwrite it in your activeadmin resource code like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    def new
      super #use the default methods and response block
      @user.activate! #if you want to add some methods
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect thanks for the hint. I totally overlooked this in the [docs] (http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html#modifying-the-controller).